# Add custom class to li element which has children

Tags: menus, walker

How I can output specific class or something else (for Example data-toggle="treeview" )for li element which has children?

I use custom walker

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Create a nav menu with very basic markup.
 *
 * @author Thomas Scholz http://toscho.de
 * @version 1.0
 */
class menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
     * @param  array $args    Additional strings.
     * @return void
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args )
    {

        $output     .= '<li>';

        $attributes  = 'class="app-menu__item"';

        ! empty ( $item->attr_title )
            // Avoid redundant titles
            and $item->attr_title !== $item->title
            and $attributes .= ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';

        ! empty ( $item->url )
            and $attributes .= ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"';



        $attributes  = trim( $attributes );
        $title       = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        $font_awesome = get_field('font_awesome', $item);
        // $item_output = "$args->before<a $attributes>$args->link_before$title</a>"
        //              . "$args->link_after$args->after";

        $item_output = "$args->before"
                        . "<a $attributes>"
                        . "<i class='app-menu__icon " . $font_awesome ."'></i>"
                        . "$args->link_before"
                        . "$title"
                        . "</a>"
                        . "$args->link_after"
                        . "$args->after";

        // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
        $output .= apply_filters(
            'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
            ,   $item_output
            ,   $item
            ,   $depth
            ,   $args
        );
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @return void
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output )
    {
        $output .= '<ul class="treeview-menu">';
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @return void
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output )
    {
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @return void
     */
    function end_el( &$output )
    {
        $output .= '</li>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this walker class ([Bootstrap Nav Walker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php#L108)) you'll get a good understanding of how things work inside a walker. There is a `has_children` property in `$args` argument `$args->has_children`. You can use this to check if the current item has any children or not like the following code

```
if ( $args->has_children ) {
    // do whatever you want
}
```